# Hexadecimal escapes to text(UTF-8), bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unicode, utf-8

I have file that consists various Unicode characters. I want to convert all those unicode characters to UTF-8. For example characters:

```
\xC3\x9C to Ü
\xC3\x96 to Ö
\xC3\xBC to ü
\xC3\xA4 to ä
and so on
```

I want to do it with one command and without install some extra stuff. I want to do it in bash script.

Comment: The operation you describe is not "Unicode to UTF-8".

Comment: It's "hexadecimal escapes to text".

Comment: There is no such thing as "Unicode to UTF-8" because UTF-8 is merely one method to encode Unicode. Hint `iconv` is your friend if you know the source encoding ...

Comment: Tried with iconv, but couldn't get it done.

Comment: @Marko: well why didn't you write this in the question? Why is there no info about the exact line you tried, nor about the encoding you're coming **from**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `echo` command:

```
$ echo -e '\xC3\x9C'
Ü
```

Or use the `printf` command

```
$ printf '\xC3\x9C'
Ü
```

Comment: Actually this will only work if and when your terminal understands UTF-8 :)

Comment: It doesnt replace all those hexadecimals to characters ÕÜÖÄõüöä.

Comment: Actually after little thinking, got it actually done like so:) Ty.