# xxd: how to simply revert without adding "00000000:"?

Tags: bash, unicode, utf-8, xxd

Sometimes I have unwanted characters in my files (DB tables, git content, etc). When I list them with `xxd` I have the UTF-8 code, e.g.:

`e28099`

I would like to know which is this character in bash, so I type:

`echo -n '00000000: e28099' | xxd -r`

And I will have

`’`

on the console. Is it possible not to include always those zeroes (`00000000:` )? So are there any params of `xxd` with which I could type:

`echo -n 'e28099' | xxd -???` and the result will be `’`?

Comment: General computer usage is not suitable for Stack Overflow. The most portable solution is to use shell builtins instead of `xxd`; try e.g. `printf '\xe2\x80\x99\n'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604270/hexadecimal-escapes-to-textutf-8-bash-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest:

```
echo 'e28099' | xxd -r -p
```

Output:

```
’
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -le'print pack "H*", $ARGV[0]' e28099
’
```

```
$ perl -Mv5.10 -Mcharnames=:full -C -e'
   $_ = pack "H*", $ARGV[0];
   utf8::decode $_;
   say;
   for my $cp ( unpack "W*", $_ ) {
      my $c = chr( $cp );
      say sprintf "%s U+%X %s",
         ( $c =~ /\p{Print}/ && !/\p{Mark}/ ) ? "[$c]" : "   ",
         $cp,
         charnames::viacode( $cp );
   }
' e28099
’
[’] U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
```

(To make them use STDIN instead of an argument, replace `-le`/`-e` with `-ple`, and replace `$ARGV[0]` with `$_`.)